# Differences between OAuth Web Server Flow, User-Agent Flow, Username-Password Flow?

Tags: oauth2

The steps for Web Server flow, Username-Password Flow, and User-Agent Flow are different, so which occasions are these three used in and how do I select any particular method for different applications. My guess is standalone applications suit Web Server Flow, browser or mobile applications suit for User-Agent Flow and Username-Password flow is used for testing purposes. Is that correct? Any different views?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

- **[Web server flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US)** (In OAuth spec terms, [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1)) tends to be used for web applications where server-side code needs to interact with Force.com APIs on the user's behalf, for example DocuSign:

[image: DocuSign Authorization]

Tokens are sent directly from the Authorization Server to the OAuth Client app, providing a high level of security.

- **[User-Agent flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&language=en_US)** ([Implicit Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2)) tends to be used for mobile or desktop applications, for example Salesforce1 or Mobile SDK apps:

[image: Mobile SDK Authorization]

Tokens are returned to the Client app via a 'hash fragment' on a URL.

- **[Username-Password flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en_US)** ([Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)) can be used for testing, or for apps that operate non-interactively, such as legacy integrations, without a user to actively give authorization:

  ```
   $ curl -d 'grant_type=password&client_id=3MV_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=1234&username=user@example.com&password=password' \
   https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

   {
     "id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/ORG_ID/USER_ID",
     "issued_at":"1385271368428",
     "instance_url":"https://na15.salesforce.com",
     "signature":"Vcz4TlGBQJCwJzNtH3AHT/kUFLM4N/sFrJODX2ZNuyE=",
     "access_token":"00D_ACCESS_TOKEN"
   }
  ```

Username-password is generally discouraged and should be used only where no other alternative is available, due to the inherent problems with passwords.

- **[SAML Bearer Assertion Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_SAML_bearer_flow.htm&language=en_US)** ([SAML 2.0 Profile for OAuth 2.0 Client Authentication and Authorization Grants](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-saml2-bearer)) is a better way for apps to obtain OAuth tokens without user interaction. The app obtains a signed SAML Assertion from an IAM system and exchanges it for the OAuth token.
- **[JWT Bearer Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&language=en_US)** ([JSON Web Token (JWT) Profile for OAuth 2.0 Client Authentication and Authorization Grants](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-jwt-bearer)) is similar to SAML Bearer Assertion Flow, but uses a signed JSON Web Token rather than the SAML (XML) Assertion.

Comment: Can you suggest the practical use for each flow?

Comment: I thought I did.

Comment: I mean examples

Comment: I don't understand - do you mean actual applications, like 'Salesforce1', and 'DocuSign'?

Comment: yes exactly.  More like chrome REST Console is user name password flow;   A java application is Webserverflow etc.

Comment: @ShebinMathew - how's that?

Comment: Which flow does the Facebook Auth Provider in Salesforce follow ?

Comment: @techtrekker - the FB Auth Provider uses Web Server flow - you can try it out at https://authtest-developer-edition.na14.force.com/