# Allowing connected app oauth to use salesforce azure ad login

Tags: connected-apps, oauth, azure-active-directory

I wants to use salesforce oauth using through connected app. But my salesforce login happening using azure ad login(open ID).

Connected App (OAUTH) -> Salesforce -> Azure AD

So Can you please suggest me/provide me steps to achieve Oauth flow using connected app for salesforce AZURE AD?

use case: At my company people are logging into salesforce though azure AD(SSO). we are planning to create new system which integrates with salesforce(pushing & pulling the data from salesforce). People wants to login to the new system using salesforce. With the connected app oauth I can able to login (salesforce form login flow) But I don't have idea of how connected app oauth flow will work for salesforce azure ad login?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Describe your goals at a higher, functional level.

Comment: At my company people are logging into salesforce though azure AD(SSO). we are planning to create new system which integrates with salesforce(pushing & pulling the data from salesforce). People wants to login to the new system using salesforce. With the connected app oauth I can able to login (salesforce form login flow) But I don't have idea of how connected app oauth flow will work for salesforce azure ad login? @identigral do you have any please help me. I'm new to salesforce system

Comment: Users logging in to new system with their Salesforce identity - look into SAML or OpenID Connect, oAuth is not the right solution for this. For integration of new system with Salesforce, take a look at [oAuth JWT Bearer flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21090/differences-between-oauth-web-server-flow-user-agent-flow-username-password-fl).